# What's better in terms of performance of a Java stream: combine filters or combine circumstances?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

There is a requirement to filter all objects that fit some circumstances for their fields. 
Assume the object has several fields:

```
class Price {
int first;
int second; 
String third; 
}
```

and stream of prices :

```
Stream<Price> streamPrices;
```

What is the best choice:

1.

```
streamPrices
    .parallel()
    .filter(p0->p0.first> 10)
    .filter(p1->p1.second <30)
    .filter(p2-> p2.third.length() > 8);
```

2.

```
streamPrices
   .parallel()
   .filter(p-> (p.first > 10) 
      && (p->p.second <30) 
      && (p-> p.third.length() > 8)
    );
```

I used JMH framework but I didn't come up to a clear conclusion.

Comment: I would consider the first one to be more readable, which is the only thing you should consider until you actually hit performance problems.

Comment: Is the 2nd example valid Java syntax? I don't think you can combine Predicates with logical and operators. I think you want to remove the lamdas and stay with only boolean expressions.

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry about performance, after all premature optimisation is the root of all evil.  It's usually far less important than well designed code that is readable and easy to maintain.

Measuring performance is tricky, especially when it comes to `streams`.  For example, for smaller lists you'll probably find that `parallel` is slower than `sequential` since the overhead of the threading outweighs the gains.  You'll also find that `streams` are generally less efficient than traditional `iterators` since streams are syntactic sugar that the compiler turns into objects and method calls.

That being said, the difference is so minuscule that it's not even worth a second thought.

Answer (score -2):

Measurements with your price class where the first filter removes 50% and the second removes the next 50% and the third filter removes 50% gave that method number 2 takes a little more than half as long as method number 1.

**Edit:** improved numbers by following Lino's suggestion in comments, slightly decreased numbers but general 50% decrease for method 1 still standing.

**Method 1: 118 ms** / 10000000 items

average: 118ms min: 107ms, max: 252ms

**Method 2: 79 ms** / 10000000 items

average: 79ms min: 70ms, max: 91ms

So **method 2** is definitely more performant, but the actual difference is less than 40ms / 10 million items on my computer so unless you are working with very large sets its negligible.

Personally I prefer method 1 for being easier to read. Method 2 can be useful if you are passing the predicate from another function.

```
public class FilterTest extends Test {
int i = 10000000;
Random random = new Random(i);
List<Price> prices;

public void setup() {
    prices = Stream.generate(new Supplier<Price>() {
        @Override
        public Price get() {
            return new Price(random);
        }
    }).limit(i).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // Method 1
    // prices.stream().parallel()
    //     .filter(p -> p.v1 > 0.5d)
    //     .filter(p -> p.v2 > 0.5d)
    //     .filter(p -> p.s.length() > 16)
    //     .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Method 2
    prices.stream().parallel()
            .filter(p -> p.v1 > 0.5d && p.v2 > 0.5 && p.s.length() > 16)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static class Price {
    double v1, v2;
    String s;

    public Price(Random random) {
        this.v1 = random.nextDouble();
        this.v2 = random.nextDouble();
        this.s = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0,(int)(32*random.nextDouble()));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I passed almost the same steps to check. I agree with you that first is more readable.

Comment: please have a look at how to [proper benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: @Lino Made the tests more proper, but general results were the same